# What does alchemy do in blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask, decentralized-applications

I am new to web3 and I am trying to deploy a contract to a blockchain.So I connected my metamask to it and in the tutorial I am following they instructed me to create an app on Alchemy.So why is it I need alchemy here.What is it exactly doing?

Answer (score 1):

Alchemy is a Web3 developer tool platform - other than being a very reliable node provider.

See it as the AWS of the Blockchain - it gives you a fully-fledged backend to deploy your decentralized Applications on most of the popular chains + gives you APIs to fetch data from the blockchain without having to scrape it all yourself.

Anyway, the best way to understand it is probably to test it - here's a doc that walks you through it:

https://docs.alchemy.com/alchemy/introduction/why-use-alchemy